# CSV write error in Python

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I have the following code:

```
def saveFile(self, master = None):
    f = asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension='.csv')
    if f is None: # asksaveasfile returns `None` if dialog closed with "cancel".
        return
    f.close()
    cords2save = globalCords # coordinates from another csv file
    csvOpen = open(f, 'w')
    w = csv.writer(fp)
    w.writerow(cords2save)
```

When I run this I get:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Jem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-     32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Jem\Documents\bbk\1FINisd\LineSimplification.py", line 143, in saveFile
csvOpen = open(f, 'w')
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper     name='C:/Users/Jem/Documents/bbk/1FINisd/ard.csv' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
```

I really am stuck as the other thread solutions don't work - what have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is this `fp` you are passing to in the one-but-last line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension='.csv')
```

`asksaveasfile` returns a file object. You then try to call `open` on that file object. But `open` doesn't expect a file, it expects a file name.

Try using `asksaveasfilename` instead.

```
def saveFile(self, master = None):
    filename = asksaveasfilename(mode='w',defaultextension='.csv')
    if not filename:
        return
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        w = csv.writer(file)
        w.writerow(globalCords)
```

Alternatively, continue to use `asksaveasfile`, but don't close the file, and don't try to open a new one.

```
def saveFile(self, master = None):
    f = asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension='.csv')
    if not f:
        return
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(globalCords)
    f.close()
```